# How to make sonar to show small code duplicates in java?

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd, code-duplication

I want to see code duplication in sonar report, and I am more strict than sonar: I want to set limit to 5 tokens.
As it turns out, the limit is not settable with the java analyzer of sonar.
So I use PMD, which successfully detect code duplications. There is even an xml report at target/cpd.xml

I see the following in sonarcube administration/general settings/external analyzers:

```
PMD Report Files
Paths (absolute or relative) to xml files with PMD issues.
Key: sonar.java.pmd.reportPaths
```

So I thought I use that. But it turns out that cpd.xml has a different structure than pmd.xml.
I could convert it with an xslt, and that will be the solution,if there is no better one.

Questions:

- Can I ask sonar to use the duplication report of PMD? or
- Can I ask sonar to use the duplication report of an other code analyzer? or
- Can I ask sonar to honour the code duplication settings

Comment: Looking at the [latest documentation (Duplications section)](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/)  the minimum value for the sonar.cpd.${language}.minimumtokens and sonar.cpd.${language}.minimumLines settings is 10.

Comment: " For Java projects, a piece of code is considered duplicated when there is a series of at least 10 statements in a row, regardless of the number of tokens and lines. This threshold cannot be overridden."
This is not good for me, and even this is tested to be not true. https://community.sonarsource.com/t/code-duplication-check-for-java-does-not-seem-to-work/7882